# How To give space tableview top and bottom 10 space in swift

Tags: uitableview

I Tried to  give space like this self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
but its not taking can any one suggests  how to do that i need space in top of Types of homes . this form design in table view [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3SnR.png)